# Как в виджете DatePicker(yii2) убрать выбор дня и оставить только выбор месяца и года?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, datepicker

Как в виджете DatePicker(yii2) убрать выбор дня и оставить только выбор месяца и года?
В документации не нашел.

Comment: Может быть вам поможет этот ответ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
```